# How to use LINQ to XML to retrieve nested arrays?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

Here's a sample of the XML I want to read:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hash>
  <result>
    <properties type="array">
      <property>
        <registers type="array">
          <register>
            <dials type="integer">6</dials>
          </register>
          <register>
            <dials type="integer">6</dials>
          </register>
        </registers>
        <unit-balance type="integer">-104</unit-balance>
      </property>
    </properties>
    <account-number>9001234</account-number>
  </result>
  <version>1.0</version>
</hash>
```

I can read the first level with the following code, but how to get the registers, and have them associated with the corresponding property?

```
var rawProperties = from property in customerXml.Descendants("property")
                    select new 
                    {
                        UnitBalance = property.Element("unit-balance").Value
                    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var rawProperties = customerXml.Descendants("property")
    .Select(arg =>
        new
        {
            UnitBalance = arg.Element("unit-balance").Value,
            Registers = arg.Descendants("dials").Select(x => x.Value).ToList()
        })
    .ToList();
```